Angular 17 template code completion not working in PhpStorm 2024.1.1
I migrated project to Angular 17.3.6. Also updated PhpStorm to 2024.1.1 and there is recent Angular plugin. I cannot get IDE to provide code completion in Angular templates. Also it doesn't recognize variables in it. Not after invalidate cache and restart IDE.
I managed only to get code coloring nothing more by assigning .component.html to Angular 17 template type. Do you have idea what could be the problem?


I tried to:

Assign *.component.html to Angular 17 template file type
Remove all node modules and package.lock and instal again
Invalidated cache and restarted several times


Hmm so I've been doing FE web dev for a very long time but I can't say I've ever seen the @ if in a template before ever... it isn't an Angular (ng-if) or vue (v-if) or React (if) thing nor is it familiar from any of the templating languages I'm familiar with or JSP/PHP... any idea what the @if is supposed to be coming from languages wise?

The @if block is part of Angular's new control flow that remplaces the old ngIf, ngFor and ngSwitch directives, as to why it is not reckognized by your PhpStorm i'm not sure, I'd say to try and see if the Angular plugin is up to date ? Maybe you can check the logs of your IDE see if there's anything there.

I have the same issue. My whole team has been holding back on upgrading from 2023.3 for this very reason for months. Very annoying that it still hasn't been fixed.
